# Adding each element in a vector yields no number

Tags: matlab, vector, sum

I have a vector,

```
a2 = [8 10 18 18]
```

I want to add all individual digits in this vector, i.e.

```
8 + 1+0 + 1+8 + 1+8 = 27
```

I decided to use the following piece of code:

```
a3 = num2str(a2)
sum2 = 0;
for k = 1:numel(a3)
    sum2 = sum2 + str2num(a3(k));
end
sum2
```

However, when I output this I get `sum2 = []`. What exactly is going wrong here? Apparently, `a3` has `13` elements, which means the spaces must be `2` elements wide. Does the issue lie there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Recommended Solution:**

Use [`num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), [`cellstr`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html), [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html), and [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) with the [`omitnan`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html#buqni15) flag.

```
req = num2str(a2);    
req = sum(str2double(cellstr(req(:))),'omitnan');
```

`num2str` converts the given matrix `a2` into a character array. `req(:)` [reshapes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html#bvhfych) the character array `req` into a column vector. It still contains spaces. `cellstr` is applied to convert the column character array into a cell array so that `str2double` can be applied. `str2double` converts the spaces into `NaN` and the char numbers into respective doubles. `sum` with the `omitnan` flag ignores the `NaN` while addition.

---

**Just another Solution:**

It can also be done using just [`num2str`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2str.html), [`str2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html), and [`sum`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html). *But [`str2num`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html) uses [`eval`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html) and hence it should be [avoided](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/)*. Anyhow just for the fun of it:

```
req = num2str(a2);
req = sum(str2num(req(:)));
```

Just like the previous solution, when `str2num` is applied on the column character array containing spaces, spaces get removed and the remaining char numbers are converted into respective doubles. The operation of the `sum` function is obvious.

---

**Why does your code not work?**

When `str2num` is applied on the space character, `[]` is returned. When `[]` is added into any number, the result is also `[]`. Since in your code `a3` contains spaces, hence you get `[]` as output.

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit the ASCII mapping:

```
b = uint64(num2str(a2') - '0')
b =
  4×2 uint64 matrix
   0   8
   1   0
   1   8
   1   8
```

and then sum:

```
sum(b(:))
ans =
    27
```

Comment: Please change the complex conjugate transpose `'` with `.'` transpose

Comment: @SardarUsama ... I take it that's your pet peeve? :p  It doesn't matter, because in this context, `a' == a.'` and there are *a lot* of other things that may go wrong before this difference is ever an issue...

Comment: Beat me to it by seconds...you can also use `sum(sum(...))` to avoid the temporary :p

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis I have seen people getting used to `'` as transpose  when dealing with real numbers and messing things up  later with complex numbers. At least it should be stated that `'` is not really transpose

Comment: @SardarUsama ...I'm not saying you're wrong, I'm saying that it's a bit pedantic. Much more important here is, for example, the behavior for when `a2` is non-numeric, or non-integer -- there is no error.

Comment: Whilst I agree with that but we shouldn't be waiting for the error to make the correction :)

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, a shorter, faster, less robust and less readable solution:

```
sum2 = sum(sprintf('%d',a2)-'0');
```

Breakdown:

- **`sprintf`** to convert all elements of `a2` to a string without space as delimiter, like `num2str` would do
- **subtracting `'0'`** implicitly casts the character array to the ASCII code equivalents. Subtracting the ASCII value for 0 then results in numbers 0-10
- **`sum()`** to complete the operation.

Note that if `a2` was a string to begin with, this solution will *not* give an error (same for the other answer, by the way)